# FormData Returning Undefined in Ajax and Wordpress Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, form-data

I created a contact form for a Wordpress theme (custom) using jQuery/Ajax. When I tested the wp_send_json_sucess with "it works" it returned as suspected. However, when I added $formdata and the name of a field on the form the from returned undefined in the JS alert box. I'm pretty sure I've typed it correctly, as I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYvx_L9ESn0. But I cannot seem to get it to work.

Code for functions.php here

```
add_action('wp_ajax_contact', 'contact_form');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_contact', 'contact_form');

function contact_form()

{
 $formdata = [];

 wp_parse_str( $_POST['contact'], $formdata );

  wp_send_json_success( $formdata ['myName'] );
}
```

Form Code Here :

```
<form  id="contact">
           Name: <input type="text" name="myName" class="contactform 
           fields" placeholder="name"required><br><br>

           Email: <input type="text" name="myEmail" class="contactform 
           fields" placeholder="you@youremail.com" required><br><br>

             <p>What is your inquiry regarding?</p><be>
               <input type="radio" name="reason" value="general">
               <label for="news">General Inquiry</label><be>
                 <input type="radio" name="reason" value="course">
                 <label for="news">Courses</label><br>

      <p class="contact_txt">Your Message:</p>
         <textarea name="msg" rows="5" cols="700" placeholder="begin 
         typing message here..." required>
         </textarea>

     <p class="contact_txt">Would you like to subscribe to our 
      newsletter?</p>
     <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="news" value="Subscribe">
      <label for="news">Yes, I would like to subscribe</label>
       <br>

          <input class="btns" name="btn-send" id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="submit">
          <input class="btns" name="btn-reset" id="myReset" type="reset" value="reset">
  </form>
```

Script Here :

```
<script>

  jQuery('#contact').submit( function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var endpoint = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
    var form = jQuery('#contact').serialize();
    var formdata = new FormData;

    formdata.append('action', 'contact');
    formdata.append('contact', 'form');

    jQuery.ajax(endpoint, {
      type: 'POST',
      data: formdata,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,

      success: function(res){
        alert(res.data);
      },

      error:function(err){

      }
    })
  })

  </script>
```

Comment: check what is the value of $formdata after wp_parse_str

Comment: and what is the 'res' value in success callback

Comment: @HWSiew I don't understand I'm really new at this...but it looks like several people that followed this tutorial ended up not getting it to work either...

Comment: in you jquery ajax success callback, console.log(res).